# Good Resources for Relational Database Design

Tags: sql, database, performance

I'm looking for a book/site/tutorial on best practices for relational database design, tuning for performance etc. It turns out this kind of resource is a bit difficult to find; there's a lot of "here's normalization, here's ER diagrams, have at it," but not much in the way of real examples. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Book: [Database Design for Mere Mortals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Library of Free Data Models](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm). There are tons of example database designs, with diagrams that cover real-world scenarios (and some just fun/funny ones as well). I haven't ever used one as-is, but it's often been handy to get an idea of how to approach the problem of mapping the needs of the situation into a data model.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "[The Art of SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596008949/)". A pleasure to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources I could find on the web. They include examples you are looking for:

- [Designing and creating a Relational Database - Dr Lorna Scammell: Newcastle University Database Adviser](http://databases.ncl.ac.uk/databases/Design/default.aspx)
- [Sample Data Models for Relational Database Design](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/data_models.html)