# Database design standards

Tags: database

I'm looking for a document/text/book about the database design standards, until now I've found [this](http://www.sba.gov/idc/groups/public/documents/sba_program_office/sba_ocio_db_design_standards.pdf) but it is a custom set of rules about design, I need something like an IEEE standard or such.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to what end? what kind of database and what are you designing? standards for database api's? standards for table structure? standards for representing commonly-recurring objects as tables?

Comment: for general guidelines this is a great resource -- http://www.amazon.com/Data-Modeling-Information-Professionals-Schmidt/dp/0130804509

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Resources for Relational Database Design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615/good-resources-for-relational-database-design)

Comment: standards for table naming conventions, lengths of fields, all about table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the book I used a few years ago when I initially learned about database design in school: [http://www.amazon.com/Database-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0073523321/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1279133097&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523321)

For online research, make sure you look into "3rd normal form" designs for your databases. It allows for the most flexibility and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing as an official IEEE standard regarding database design. However there is the [Entity-Relationship-Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) and the theory of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). For the more mathematically inclined there is [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

It is also common to make a distinction between physical, logical and conceptual schemata in database design. What is most important area of those 3 would also determine in what kind of material you should be looking into.